# How to filter only a specific query log in spring (logback.xml)

Tags: java, spring, filter, logback

I am using logback-spring.xml file to log sql results. And also I use "SqlSessionTemplate" as a common jdbcTemplate to write sql queries and get data from database.
In this situation, I need to except some logs because it has a lot of data which is loaded when server booted and useless. But as I mentioned above, I use the same templates so I don't know how to filter only that query from logging.
I have tried to filter it as I make a Interceptor like below.

logback-spring.xml

```
<appender name="STDOUT-SQL-RESULTSET" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="com.common.interceptor.LogbackInterceptor" />
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
</appender>
```

LogbackInterceptor.java

```
public class LogbackInterceptor extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide( ILoggingEvent event ) {
        if (event.getMessage().contains("NOT_SQL_LOG")) {
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        }else{
            return FilterReply.ACCEPT;
        }
    }
}
```

messageSql.xml

```
<select id="retrieveMessage" parameterType="String" resultType="Message">
  -- NOT_SQL_LOG
  SELECT blahblah ~~
```

As the result has many rows, only the comment line "-- NOT_SQL_LOG" was skipped and the other queries and results all came out to console log.

And when I tired EvaluatorFilter, server didn't start leaving message like "[main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading"

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator>
            <expression>return message.contains("NOT_SQL_LOG");</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
</filter>
```

Please help me to filter specific queries not to be written.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding mdc

Comment: Can you provide more details on how MDC solved your problem?